# MySQL: Select Order Only if all its Items are ready status

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I will simplify the table like this:

```
table order:
order_id | name
1          a
2          b
3          c

Table order_item:
item_id | fk_order_id | status
1         1             0
2         1             1
3         2             1
4         2             1
5         3             0
```

Ready status let say is 1, so only order_id=2 has all its items are on ready status.

How can I query select it?

Comment: join tables and put where condition

Comment: If I use simple join and where condition, it wont be enough because I have to make sure all its items are ready first, not partial. The query result should be order_id 2 because its item_id 3 and 4 are both ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this -- here is one using `COUNT` -- gets `COUNT` of all and compares to `COUNT` of Status = 1:

```
SELECT fk_order_id
FROM (
  SELECT fk_order_id, 
     COUNT(1) totCount, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 END) statusCount
  FROM Order_Item
  GROUP BY fk_order_id
) t
WHERE totCount = statusCount
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81d1a/2)

This could be consolidated into a single query, but I think it reads better using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SELECT order_id ,name FROM order,order_item 
WHERE order.order_id =order_item.fk_order_id 
group by order_id ,name having min(status)=1